# ES6 Can't return a new Promise after current Promise finished

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I need somehow to chain Promises and I found out that Promise then can do the job.

My requirement is like:
`addressService.get` return a address, once I get this address and use this to do another call which also return a Promise.

So my code is like:

```
class PersonService {
  getPerson() {
    addressService.get().then(({address}) => {
      return 'http://localhost/${address}'
    }).then(url) {
      return new es6Promise.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ApiUtils.get(url, {}, {}, {
          success: resolve, error: reject
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The `PersonService's getPerson` should also return a Promise which is the second Promise I returned (ApiUtils.get)

However, it seems the above code doesn't return a Promise, as when I call `PersonService.getPerson().then()` in some other place, I got an error said that

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Did I miss something here?

Comment: You have syntax error this line `.then(url) {` and get() not return returning promise, please add the code for `addressService.get`

Comment: Are those really backticks, because they look like single ticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `getPerson()` returns nothing. You are missing a `return` keyword.

Correct structure is:

```
getPerson() {
 return addressService.get()
                      .then(...)
                      .then(...);
}
```

---

Side note: There are also several other typos/minor errors to fix:

```
class PersonService {
  getPerson() {
    return addressService.get().then(({address}) => { // <== Added return at beginning of line
      return `http://localhost/${address}`;           // <== Use ` (backtick), not ', for template strings
    }).then(url => {                                  // <== Fixed typo
      return new es6Promise.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ApiUtils.get(url, {}, {}, {
          success: resolve, error: reject
        });
      });
    });                                               // <== Fixed typo
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'm in favor of letting tools (compilers, interpreters, REPLs, debuggers) find typos, not humans. It's easier and faster and you don't have to wait for a human on SO to reply. Actually, this whole question is about a bunch of typos, if you include leaving out return as a particular kind of typo, so the question should be closed as a typo.

Comment: @torazaburo I don't quite agree. The main error, which was my only answer before my post was edited with the other typos, is that the OP failed to understand `.then()` returns a Promise itself and should be returned by `getPerson()`. Actually the question was: "how to return the inner promise", which is not a good idea and a misunderstanding of how Promises work. This is not a typo. It was valid JS, although not working.